# How to extract the number from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have my below string as

```
String version = "v2";
```

here version can be any of these values -

```
v3
v4
v5
..
v10
v11
..
v100
..
v500
..
v1000
```

I would like to extract number from the above string so which could be `2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 100, 500, 1000` from it.

What is the correct way to extract only the number from it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the first character is always `'v'`, then remove it from the string, then call `Integer.parseInt`:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(version.substring(1));
```

Comment: you may want to try and catch the NumberFormatException too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(your string);
    while (m.find()) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
```